# Грамотно ли употреблять словосочетание "оживлённое движение"?

Tags: употребление-слов

Грамотно ли употреблять словосочетание "оживлённое движение"?
Ведь само слово "оживлённо" указывает на приведение из статики в динамику. В семиотике смерть - статика, а оживить значит придать динамику, но само "движение" будучи в единственном числе не может быть не "динамическим", не "статическим"

Answer (score 6):

Почему нет?

> Оживленный 2. Протекающий особенно живо, активно. О-ая переписка, деятельность. О-ое движение на дорогах. Вести оживлённую торговлю, беседу. О. товарообмен, показ новых моделей одежды.

Comment: Это Кузнецов, как я понимаю.
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%EE%E6%E8%E2%EB%E5%ED%ED%FB%E9&all=x

Answer (score 4):

Оживить по Ожегову

1. возвратить к жизни, сделать живым,
2. придать сил, энергии, живости,
3. наполнить движением, деятельностью,
4. сделать активным, более деятельным

Движение может быть оживлённым, активным, а может быть пассивным,не энергичным.Говорим же мы "двигайся поживее", т.е. поэнергичнее, так что никакого противоречия здесь нет, выражение грамотное, литературное.